How do I export my history from Opera GX
There are many answers dealing with bookmarks or regular Opera (there is no "profile" path shown for me in Opera GX), but I can't quite seem to find instructions on how to export my history from Opera GX.
(In my particular case, I want to switch from Opera GX back to Chrome and merge my history with Chrome's, and this answer does not work for me; Chrome only detects Microsoft Explorer. And this one says it doesn't have an answer.)

I switched over to Opera GX a few months ago and would like to merge my old Chrome history with the Opera GX history for a full Chrome history that covers those few months.

I view a lot of informative media online (documentaries on YouTube, articles on LessWrong, etc.) and sometimes forget to save them to my Zotero, so it's really nice to be able to search my history for everything. myactivity on Google is nice, but if I follow a link from one page to another (e.g. on LessWrong), it's not tracked there, but it is in my history.

From
How to View Browsing History on Opera GX:

Importing History from Other Browsers
If you are moving from another browser to Opera GX and want to bring
your browsing history with you, you can do so by importing it. To
import browsing history, go to the Opera settings and click on the
Import bookmarks and settings option. From there, you can choose the
browser from which you want to import data.
Exporting Your Opera GX Browsing History
If you want to export your browsing history from Opera GX, go to the
Opera settings and click on the Export bookmarks and settings option.
From there, select Browsing History and save the file to your
preferred location. You can then transfer the file to another device
or upload it to cloud storage.


If I search "bookmarks and settings" in Opera GX settings, the only option that comes up is to "import bookmarks and settings", not to export them. If I go to opera://bookmarks/, there is an option to export, but it is only for bookmarks, not history.

If the documentation doesn't describe the product, you may try to reinstall the latest version. If the contradiction still exists, you should contact Support to find why.

Sounds good, thank you for your help!

Also, the information you quoted is not from Opera GX, so I don't think it's documentation.

This link came from a gaming operating system called SigmaOS which might be using a modified version of Opera GX that's different from yours. If this link does not apply to you, in classic Opera the history is maintained in the "History" file found in the profile folder. This file is said to be compatible with chrome's History file and can even replace it or be imported.
